# How do I convert bibtex citation commands into R markdown format in R?

Tags: string, latex, r-markdown, bibtex, citations

I have a dataframe in R, one column of which contains bibtex citation commands, such as the following

```
\\cite[265]{delbarrio2014a}, \\cite[423--429]{nieto2009}, \\cite[188, 191, 196--197]{bile1988a}, \\cite[188--189]{bartonek2003}, \\cite[193]{thompson2010}, \\cite{skelton2015}
```

I want to make an HTML document with these citations in R Markdown. To do that, they need to be in the format `@author, page number` (if there is a page number). How do I convert the strings above into this format? For instance, `\\cite[265]{delbarrio2014a}` should become `@delbarrio2014a, 265`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
data.frame(string = c(
  "\\cite[265]{delbarrio2014a}",
  "\\cite[423--429]{nieto2009}",
  "\\cite[188, 191, 196--197]{bile1988a}"
)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(citation = paste0(
    "@", stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})"), ", ",
    stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
  ))
```

**Result:**

```
                                 string                       citation
1           \\cite[265]{delbarrio2014a}           @delbarrio2014a, 265
2           \\cite[423--429]{nieto2009}           @nieto2009, 423--429
3 \\cite[188, 191, 196--197]{bile1988a} @bile1988a, 188, 191, 196--197
```